# Help me fix my website - which used to rotate homepage images on underlying image map

Tags: html, web, cgi, web-hosting

Title: Rotate Homepage Image (for website)- No longer works.
I am a physicist/wildlife artist with a website (I created in 2002) to display & market my artwork.  I have set it up with an underlying (homepage) image map - having links to: "tigers", "leopards", "birds", artist info, etc., with the overlying image changing (swapping out) every time the user navigates to/from homepage. The links for each homepage have the same numerical coordinates and do not change locations from page to page, just the image changes.   You can see my blank-page site at www.querryart.com. Note links below DO work.

The website was fabulous until last year.  At that time my former webhost went out of business, and I changed to Jumpline.com.  Since then, the commands which call canned subroutines do not work.

The routine which swaps out the image is named pid.cgi (stored in the cgi-bin).

Another one-line page-counter cgi routine I used at the end of each page called a canned program "count.cgi" which counted visitors to that page, incremented "hits" per page, and stored them in a table displayed only to me.  This was a way I could determine the popularity of various images. This cgi routine also does not now work - giving me an error message on each page.

Anyway, I am lost without these routines (particularly the first one to swap out images). Is it progress that my Cadillac website has turned into an empty wagon?  Hope someone can help.  I'm not a programmer.

Comment: Try posting a "help wanted" ad.

Comment: In what way do they "not work"? What error message is given?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you may need to change the line(s) at the top of your CGI file in order for the server to process them. For example, if using Perl, `#!/usr/bin/perl` is a common directory, and so is `#!/usr/local/bin/perl`.

Oh, and have you set the permissions to 755?

Comment: Out of frustration (believing that my new host will not allow cgi scripts) I have recreated my homepage as a single image map which does not swap out ("rotate") painting (homepage) images.  This should also eliminate any security problems with "...dicont.cnf".  "Can't fight "City Hall"!  Thanks for your good thoughts and suggestions.  Check out the revised site - for glamour if not for programming brilliance(tsk tsk)! 

www.querryart.com

Thanks again for your help, Diane Querry

Answer (score 0):

For starters: http://www.querryart.com/cgi-bin/pid.cgi  does not exist. You might want to make sure the file is uploaded to the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that your host supports CGI scripts.
2. Make sure, your CGI scripts are uploaded at the correct location according to the info from your host regarding the installation of CGI scripts.
3. Make sure the scripts are executable (chmod 755)
4. Make sure, that the scripts are calling the correct interpreter (as pointed out by Steve).

From a quick check at your web site, it looks like the scripts are not in the right place because the webserver gives a 404 - not found. when I try to get /cgi-bin/pid.cgi

Furthermore, the fact that the script takes an absolute path as a parameter (cfile=/home/querryar/httpdocs/cgi-bin/dicont.cnf) looks like a glaring security problem allowing access to any files in your account. You should really consider a different solution